# Facing slowness in Channel sync Operation in Hyperledger Fabric v2.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a hyperledger fabric network with 3 orgs named org1, org2 and org3 with a system-channel named "sys-channel" and an app channel named "mychannel". Due to some reason, I had removed org3 from both system-channel and application channel. And added again after regenerating new certs. But now the peer of org3 is taking longer time than usual to get synced with the application channel which has around 100k blocks. In time of around 10 hours, only 7k blocks got synced.

Same scenario, when I add new org named org4 to the network, the complete channel sync is getting done in around an hour.

Could anyone explain me the cause for this delay in channel syncing?